# Changing size between lines with Unity3D's GUIText

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3d GUIText for my GUI.

How can I change the size between lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUIText [has a lineSpacing attribute](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUIText-lineSpacing.html). I'm assuming that is what you're referring to with "size between lines". If so, it's as simple as something like:

```c#
guiText.lineSpacing = 1.0; //or whatever value you desire
```

The effect would be something like the following:

[image]