# How can I change size between lines in Unity3D's GUILabel

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

For my GUI I am using GUILabel.

How can I change the size between lines?

Comment: FWIW these days (2016), do not use GUI at all. Fortunately in the new UI system, it's very simple to do this for UI.Text http://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-lineSpacing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unlike a GUIText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921723/changing-size-between-lines-with-unity3ds-guitext) there is no way to set line spacing for a GUILabel.

While a GUILabel is able to show multi-line text, to adjust the spacing you would have to insert extra newlines or modify the font used.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the line height if you create a editable copy of the font, you just have to click in the font (in the Assets panel), go to the gear icon of the Inspector panel and click **"Create Editable Copy"**. The new copy on the Assets panel has a parameter called **"Line Spacing"** that you can modify at will.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to assign a GUIStyle to your label then you can use:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUIStyle-lineHeight.html

== EDIT ==

lineHeight is readonly ... seems not possible currently.. try modifying the font instead

Comment: sorry then probably better to modify the font you are using